# О числительных

Tags: стилистика, числительные

Часто, работая с письмами в редакцию, сталкиваюсь с тем, что люди, для простоты и краткости, в текстах пишут числа цифрами (тексты - истории из жизни, которые потом публикуются в газете). Я обычно исправляю на слова все, кроме дат. Хотелось бы знать, допустимы ли цифры в литературных текстах и, если да, то в каких случаях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цифры в текстах - вполне нормально. Часто встречается рекомендация писать словами целые числа от одного до десяти, но она тоже не носит императивного характера.
Если не секрет, что это за редакция, где так требовательны к письмам читателей? Обычно если и правят, то только самые вопиющие случаи безграмотности.

Comment: Редакция крымская, а правлю числительные я. Мне кажется, что словами (от одного до десяти) выглядит красивее.

Comment: Ясно. Не буду рассуждать о правилах работы с письмами вообще. У вас, конечно, специфика, которой я не знаю. А что знаю, то очень однобоко.

А про цифры - смотрите по месту, от читателя зависит. Математику вряд ли "четыре" покажется красивее чем "4".